# Deriving force between continuous distributions of two volume charges without using infinitesimals

Tags: forces, electrostatics, integration, mathematics

We know that force between two point charges is:

$$\vec{F}=k\ q\ q'\ \dfrac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\tag1$$

From here how shall we derive the equation for force between *continuous distributions* of two volume charges, i.e.

$$\vec{F}=k\ \int_{q} \int_{q'} \dfrac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\ dq'\ dq \tag2$$

> **EDIT:**
>
> We are using only Cartesian Geometry here. We divide the charges $q$ and $q'$ into equal cubes. Then we choose the smallest and the largest $r$ in that cube, and do the same for all cubes. Then construct the upper sum and lower sum. For a refinement of this partition, we get a set of different $r$s.

Unlike physicists and physics teachers, I want to **derive it in a rigorous way by not using infinitesimals**. I know it is pretty simple using the infinitesimal argument. We replace the two point charges $q'$ and $q$ with infinitesimal charges $\ dq'$ and $\ dq$ respectively. Then add up the infinitesimal bits over the volume to obtain $(2)$.

**Please give the in between steps to reach equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$.**

Comment: If you want it done differently you should do it and show the physicists the right way.

Comment: How can I do it right now, being a student? Anyway I want a method using standard calculus. Is there anything wrong in it?

Comment: You say that you want to derive it in a rigorous way.

Comment: in standard calculus rigorous way

Comment: Yes,  you did not ask a question.  Just express something you want to do.

Comment: As I told in the question, I need the in between steps to reach equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$ in standard calculus rigorous way.

Comment: your question is unclear as neither $\hat r$ nor $r$ are *rigorously* defined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you won't make a lot of friends in the physics stackexchange by saying "unlike physicists, I want to do this and that rigorously". What do you mean by rigorous? Because the formula you want to arrive at isn't rigorous, either. You can see this by thinking what is the $\hat{r}/r^2$ in your integrand. If you have two charge distributions, how do you define their distance?

You can start by deriving the force of a charge distribution on a point charge from the Poisson equation for the electric potential:
$\nabla^2\phi(\mathbf{r}) = -\rho(\mathbf{r})/\epsilon_0$.

Then instead of a point charge at $\mathbf{r}'$, you integrate over the other charge distribution. But as a warning: you are going to run into problems if the two charge distributions have a non-empty intersection of supports (i.e. if $\mathrm{supp}(\rho_1) \cap \mathrm{supp}(\rho_2) \neq \emptyset$).

Comment: "If you have two charge distributions, how do you define their distance?" (1) distance between the center of two cubes each of side $a$ with which we have partitioned our continuous charge distribution. (2) By the way I am only considering the case with the two charge distributions have a empty intersection.

Comment: (2): yes thats my point, you won't be able to define two charge distributions if they'd intersect. (1): no, thats not how you do it. Why a cube? Why not a cylinder? Why not a sphere? Be more rigorous. There is an analog problem for the gravitational force between two mass distributions. There you can simplify the problem to two point-like objects with the total mass of their mass distributions placed at their respective center of masses. In your problem you have to replace the center of mass with something else. Look at the integral expression, you should see it immedeatly.

Comment: (1) I am only considering Cartesian geometry. It is true that in spherical and cylindrical coordinates we get the same value for integral. But that is a different subject.

Comment: What are you talking about? What does anything I just wrote have to do with the coordinate system you choose? Take some advice from me: you are clearly in an early stage of your education. If something doesn't make sense to you immedeatly, take some time to try to understand what was said to you instead of thinking that it was wrong or not the answer you where looking for. People will stop giving you advice or offering you help if you don't take it.

Comment: And to go on with my rant: literally EVERY physicist knows how to derive that rigorously. It's just less to write it with infinitessimal charges, its a shortcut if you will.